# Erro em atributo DateTime no C# gravando no MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datetime, ado.net

Estou tentando inserir no Banco de dados MySQL a data de nascimento do usuário, no C# o atributo data_nascimento é do tipo `DateTime` e no MySQL o atributo data_nascimento é do tipo `Date`, para inserir C# estou fazendo fazendo assim:

```
DateTime nascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(txNascimento.Text);
bDep.Data_nascimento = nascimento;
```

Obs:. `bDep` é a classe básica do dependente

E na classe de dados do dependente estou **inserindo** assim:

```
public void insertDependente (BDependente bDep) {
      string sql = "INSERT INTO dependente(id_funcionario, nome, grau_parentesco, data_nascimento) ";
             sql += "VALUES ("+bDep.Funcionario.Id_funcionario+", '"+bDep.Nome+"', '"+bDep.Grau_parentesco+"', '"+bDep.Data_nascimento+"')";
            conn.update(sql);
        }
```

estou **selecionando** assim:

```
string sql = "SELECT id_dependente, id_funcionario, nome, grau_parentesco, data_nascimento ";
       sql += "FROM dependente";
                while (mdr.Read()) {
                    BDependente bDepe = new BDependente();
                    bDepe.Id_dependente      = mdr.GetInt16("id_dependente");
                    bDepe.Funcionario.Id_funcionario = mdr.GetInt16("id_funcionario");
                    bDepe.Nome               = mdr.GetString("nome");
                    bDepe.Grau_parentesco    = mdr.GetString("grau_parentesco");
                    bDepe.Data_nascimento    = mdr.GetDateTime("data_nascimento");
                    lDep.Add(bDepe);
                }
```

Sempre que eu cadastro um novo dependente no banco aparece assim:

[image: linhas do banco de dados]

O primeiro registro foi feito no próprio MySQL, e mesmo assim quando eu procuro no C# ele traz o horário e quando eu procuro no C# o outro dependente, aparece esse outro erro:

[image: Mensagem de erro]
[image: Como aparece na aplicação]

Comment: O erro só ocorre quando a data está gravada errada ou acontece em qualquer linha que tem data?

Comment: O Erro acontece na hora de gravar ! E na hora que eu faço um `SELECT` no banco

Comment: Não foi o que eu perguntei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema começa na gravação. Não é assim que se faz. Tem um enorme problema de segurança em fazer isso além de gerar este tipo de problema.

Pelo que entendi o erro na leitura ocorre porque a gravação falhou.

Teria que mudar para algo mais ou menos assim:

```
var sqlInsert = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into dependente (id_funcionario, nome, grau_parentesco, data_nascimento)
                    VALUES (@id_funcionario, @nome, @grau_parentesco, @data_nascimento)", conn);
sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_funcionario", bDep.Funcionario.Id_funcionario);
sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", bDep.Nome);
sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grau_parentesco", bDep.Grau_parentesco);
sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_nascimento", bDep.Data_nascimento.ToShortDateString());
sqlInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/SafeInsert.cs).

Aí você vai adaptar para sua necessidade. E por favor, nunca mais tente gravar desta maneira.

O ideal seria não usar variáveis com [notação húngara](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_h%C3%BAngara) também.

- [`ToShortDateString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToShortDateString)
- [`SqlCommand`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

[Não sou fá do termo atributo, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: Queria saber como vou fazer isso usando uma classe de conexão:

Comment: public void connecting()    {
            string url = "server=localhost; database=atvfuncionario; uid=root; password=''; convert zero datetime=True";
            conn = new MySqlConnection(url);
            conn.Open();
        }
        public void disconnecting() {
            conn.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }

Comment: Isto já é outro problema e só com estas informações eu não saberia dizer. Me parece que nem precisa mudar nada com relação a isto. Claro que o que esta classe parece ser um código errado, mas como eu disse, é outro problema.

Comment: A Inserção continua com erro ! ele inseri a data `0000-00-00`

Comment: É assim que se faz, não sei se tem algum outro problema.

Comment: `bDep.Data_nascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(txNascimento.Text);` É dessa forma que faz pra inserir ?

Comment: olha esse comentário acima !

Comment: Eu acho que você está com outro problema e pelo que está na pergunta não tem como saber. Quando é assim precisa fornecer um [mcve]. Mas provavelmente isto já seria outra pergunta.

Comment: Ajudou bastante ! :/

Comment: @IkaroSales a linha `sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_nascimento", bDep.Data_nascimento.ToShortDateString());` da resposta está errada, pois ela depende da cultura corrente, cujo formato pode ser diferente do aceito pelo MySql. O correto é `sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_nascimento", bDep.Data_nascimento);`, sem o *ToShortDateString*. Isso fará com que o parâmetro data seja informado como tipo data de fato (sendo convertido internamente pelo driver para o formato data do banco de dados) e resolverá o seu problema.