# Erro ao tratar exceções - "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto"

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, nullpointerexception

```
public String IdentificarAcessoDAL(FuncionarioDTO acesso)
    {
        try
        {
            conexao.cmd.Connection = conexao.conexao;
            string recuperar = "SELECT CARGO.NOME_CARGO FROM LOGIN INNER JOIN FUNCIONARIO ON FUNCIONARIO.CPF_FUNCIONARIO = LOGIN.CPF_FUNCIONARIO INNER JOIN CARGO ON CARGO.ID_CARGO = FUNCIONARIO.ID_CARGO WHERE LOGIN.USUARIO_LOGIN = '" + acesso.User + "' AND LOGIN.SENHA_LOGIN = '" + acesso.Password + "'";
            conexao.cmd.CommandText = recuperar;

            conexao.conexao.Open();
            return funcionarioDTO.Funcao = conexao.cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw erro;
        }
        finally
        {
            conexao.conexao.Close();
        }
    }
```

Sempre que digito as informações corretas ele executa a aplicação perfeitamente, mas quando ele não encontra no banco de dados, ele simplesmente para a execução do programa e exibe o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro NullReferenceException no throw]

O programa busca o cargo do funcionário, e para isso ele usa o *login* e a senha, e este erro só aparece quando o login e/ou a senha estão incorretos, caso contrario funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Quando ocorre a exceção, quais os valores de `conexao.conexao`, `acesso.User` e `acesso.Password`? Na verdade, chuto que nesse momento o objeto `acesso` não esteja setado. Você pode também remarcar os comandos `try`/`catch` para ver exatamente em que linha ocorre a exceção.

Comment: Na classe Connection "public MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection(@"server=179.188.16.199;database=oticabd;Uid=oticabd;Pwd=senha123;");" \\ e na classe FuncionarioDAL " Connection conexao = new Connection(); ", como assim o acesso não esta setado? eles recebem o valor de Textbox's, ocorre tudo corretamente quando o valor é digitado e igual aos que tem no banco de dados, quando ele não encontra, ele começa a dar esse problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String IdentificarAcessoDAL(FuncionarioDTO acesso) {
    try {
        conexao.cmd.Connection = conexao.conexao;
        conexao.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CARGO.NOME_CARGO FROM LOGIN INNER JOIN FUNCIONARIO ON FUNCIONARIO.CPF_FUNCIONARIO = LOGIN.CPF_FUNCIONARIO INNER JOIN CARGO ON CARGO.ID_CARGO = FUNCIONARIO.ID_CARGO WHERE LOGIN.USUARIO_LOGIN = '" + acesso.User + "' AND LOGIN.SENHA_LOGIN = '" + acesso.Password + "'";
        conexao.conexao.Open();
        return funcionarioDTO.Funcao = conexao.cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    } finally {
        conexao.conexao.Close();
    }
}
```

Pronto, simples.

O código ainda não está bom. Certamente esse controle de conexão é algo mal feito e isto precisaria ser arrumado, mas não é o foco da pergunta. A arquitetura desta aplicação certamente é fonte de problemas que está tendo e terá no futuro, eu simplificaria isto.

A solução foi simples porque estava fazendo algo desnecessário aí. Pra que capturar uma exceção para fazer nada? Exceções existem para propagar o erro, só capture quando sabe o que fazer com ele e resolvê-lo adequadamente, não faz sentido capturar para fazer nada.

Eu preferia fazer assim que é mais simples de gerenciar:

```
public String IdentificarAcessoDAL(FuncionarioDTO acesso) {
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CARGO.NOME_CARGO FROM LOGIN INNER JOIN FUNCIONARIO ON FUNCIONARIO.CPF_FUNCIONARIO = LOGIN.CPF_FUNCIONARIO INNER JOIN CARGO ON CARGO.ID_CARGO = FUNCIONARIO.ID_CARGO WHERE LOGIN.USUARIO_LOGIN = '" + acesso.User + "' AND LOGIN.SENHA_LOGIN = '" + acesso.Password + "'", connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/DatabaseFailing.cs).

Mentira, eu faria mais simples ainda, mas depende de uma arquitetura específica, não é o foco da pergunta e é algo amplo demais para por em uma resposta.

ATENÇÂO! Eu não consertei o grave problema de segurança que tem na aplicação, foquei só no problema específico. [Veja o correto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125739/101). [Outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104614/101).

Comment: Fiz isso mas o meu problema agora esta no " return funcionarioDTO.Funcao = conexao.cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); ", dando o seguinte erro " System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.' ", vc disse que a estrutura do meu código tem falhas que vão me dar problemas futuros e etc... você conhece algum site ou algum material que ensine sobre isso? quero aprender sobre... Obg pela ajuda

Comment: Aí é outro erro diferente do que está na pergunta, e mostra que o que estava fazendo era muito prejudicial porque estava escondendo o real erro. Um desses objetos está nulo e deveria ser instanciado, mas não temos como saber porque o problema parte de outro lugar. De qualquer forma minha sugestão é aprender o básico (esse é um erro bem básico) antes de tentar fazer coisas complexas. Não adianta tentar programar sem entender o que está acontecendo no código.